# How to create Simple View & Responsive View & linkup with one link in drupal 7?

Tags: views, theming

I am working on a commerce site (Already developed). I have seen that :

Two views are there i.e. **Product Company Accordion** View & **Product Company Slideshow** View. Both the views holds the same data. When the link `mysite/dis/product`  opened in Desktop **Product Company Slideshow** Views shows & when the same link `mysite/dis/product` opened in any mobile then **Product Company Accordion** Views shows.

I have checked these Views.

In **Product Company Accordion** View

**Format :** [Views Accordion](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_accordion)

My question is that how they apply condition with same link opened with multiple view with multiple platform.

Please help. Thanks

Comment: Responsive is responsive, no matter whether it is desktop or phone. It depends on the media query, and not on device detection. First get an idea of how you want the view data to re-flow as the screen shrinks/grows, then implement the CSS for it. If you use a framework (like bootstrap) you just add the classes in the view-rows and fields and the framework does it for you. Otherwise you need to implement media queries yourself. And stay away from table layout, unless mandated by design.

Comment: I'll update my question. Please wait for a minute.

Comment: What happens when you resize your browser on desktop. These views can show/hide depending on the media query. Also inspect the dom to see if both are there, just hidden etc. And javascript can also be used to detect screen size, and hide/show elements.

Comment: When I opened the link on desktop it shows normal & after resizing my browser on desktop it shows like another View.

Comment: You have to create views field tpl file display the contents in that like for desktop the div is different and for mobile div is different like for ex.

for desktop <div class ="dekstop"><?php print $fields; ?></div>.
for mobile <div class ="mobile"><?php print $fields; ?></div>.

now hide divs according to media queries....

Comment: Here I feels that you need to add both views on the page (use panel for same path), and add different class on both like `desktop-view`, `mobile-view`. Use media query to add css for both to display none and block.

Comment: @SumitMadan I agree. Both are rendered, but CSS will hide one of the two depending on media query.

Comment: Thanks @SumitMadan. This is a already developed site. I was checked that two views are created of type block. But I have checked that no any panel is created, no link is created from **admin/structure/pages**. I have checked through firebug, both have different css. Then how these views call through one link.

Comment: No you do not need to create a different view you just need to include a field twice on a tpl like we do in html responsive design hide the mobile view div on dekstop and hide dekstop view div in  mobile view.

in your views-view-fields.tpl.php print twice your fields one on desktop view other in mobile view like :<div id = "desktop"><?php print $field->content; ?></div>
<div id = "mobile"><?php print $field->content; ?></div>. hide #mobile for dekstop view &vice-versa

Comment: I have checked in already developed site, two views are there of type block. What tpl file you are talking about. Please explain. @harsh

Comment: `<?php foreach ($fields as $id => $field): ?>
  <?php if (!empty($field->separator)): ?>
    <?php print $field->separator; ?>
  <?php endif; ?>

  <?php print $field->wrapper_prefix; ?>
    <?php print $field->label_html; ?>
    <?php print $field->content; ?>
  <?php print $field->wrapper_suffix; ?>
<?php endforeach; ?>` Only this code are there inside **views-view-fields.tpl.php**

Comment: I agree with you @SumitMadan. But I had already told that this site is already developed & I have checked that inside **Admin->Structure->Page** no link is created & no panel is created.

Comment: @samzha may be this page is created using any custom module in which views_embed_view is used.

Comment: in views->advanced->theme information find views-view-fields.tpl.php or specific to your view.